# Flask host_matching and static files when using multiple top-level domains

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

So I have two domains:

```
MAIN_DOMAIN = www.example.com
DUTCH_DOMAIN = www.voorbeeld.com
```

I want to use the dutch domain with Flask-Babel for i18n support.

To make this possible I'm using host_matching like this:

```
def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__, host_matching=True,
                static_host=MAIN_DOMAIN)
```

Finally, routing:

```
@bp.route('/', host=MAIN_DOMAIN)
@bp.route('/', host=DUTCH_DOMAIN)
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I might want to change the routing part in the future. But for now this works fine.

Now for the problem, when I navigate to the dutch domain everything works, except that I get many 404 error messages because it can't find the static files. If I change the url of the static files to the MAIN_DOMAIN it works fine. Which makes sense since static_host is set to MAIN_DOMAIN.

So I just can't seem to find a solution for this problem. Is there a way to make both domains for static files work? Or how would you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I've figured it out and actually noticed some interesting behaviour.

So when I go to the main domain. url_for works as expected, so if you would do something like this in your templates:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery/dist/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

The result would be this:

```
<script src="/static/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However, when I go to the DUTCH_DOMAIN route I get:

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/static/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So you don't have to manually add _external=True to url_for for you other domains but it all happens automagically. The reason it didn't work before is because of CORS since from the browser point of view you're loading assets from a different domain instead of from the "local" website.

Hope this helps.